# rm or wget fail in script based on a variable with a glob

Tags: bash, wildcards, mv, phpmyadmin

I'm having a trouble either with a filename glob in `rm` or with a variable expansion in `wget`.

In Ubuntu 16.04, I did the following:

```
set -a
export drt="/var/www/html"
export pma="[pP][hH][pP][mM][yY][aA][dD][mM][iI][nN]"
set +a
echo $drt # Got the above.
echo $pma # Got the above.
```

I then ran that an executable script (`~/myScripts/tp_pma.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf ${drt}/${pma}*
wget -P ${drt} https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
unzip ${drt}/${pma}*.zip
mv ${drt}/${pma}*/ ${drt}/phpmyadmin/
rm ${drt}/${pma}*.zip
```

The script succeeded partially:

1. The first `rm` might have succeed or might have caused all problems below.
2. The `wget` succeeded partially - a zip with a fresh copy of PMA was downloaded to my home directory instead to `drt`.
3. The `unzip` succeeded, the zip was unzipped and I got a latest phpmyadmin dir.
4. The `mv` failed (see error below). Because the directory `phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages` stayed in my home directory: it wasn't moved to `drt` and didn't have its name changed to `phpmyadmin` as I expected.
5. The last `rm` succeeded - the zip was deleted in my home directory.

I didn't get an error fr `wget`.

Also, it seems that the value of `pma` changed somehow to `phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages`. I didn't change it to that value.

What is likely to have failed here and why?

Comment: BTW, those aren’t regular expressions, they’re shell globs.

Comment: So how could I target the phpmyadmin file name (zip and dir)?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from telling `wget` to write to a specific file name with `-O filename.zip` and then use that name. That will get rid of that unmaintainable shell globbing pattern. But then again, you already specify the explicit name of the file at the end of the URL, so why use a shell glob in the first case?

Comment: The `echo $pma` only outputs the pattern because of luck. If you have a file/directory matching the pattern in the current directory, you get that name instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda, because the directory name inside the archive varies.

Comment: @ilkkachu Still, the `${pma}*.zip` could definitely go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unzip` command you used extracts the archive in the directory `unzip` runs in, not where the archive lies in. You could either change to the directory containing the archive first, or use [the `-d` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip):

> `[-d exdir]`
>   An optional directory to which to extract files.  By default, all files    and subdirectories are recreated in the
>   current directory;

I would probably go with the chdir option:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$drt"
rm -r ${pma}*
wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
unzip phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
mv ${pma}*/ phpmyadmin/
rm phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
```

Also, when you say "the value of `pma` changed somehow to `phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages`", do note that using the variable unquoted will cause it to be used as a filename pattern, so `echo $pma*` will show the names of the existing files if any match the pattern.

(I'm not exactly sure if the case-insensitive pattern is required; is there a realistic reason to expect the name format to change from `phpMyAdmin` to `phpmyadmin`?)

Comment: I miss why the wget failed --- the file was downloaded to my home dir instead to `${drt}`.

Comment: @user9303970, I can't reproduce that. Even if `drt` was unset in the script, it wasn't quoted in the `wget` command, so that argument would disappear and `wget` should complain about a missing URL.

Comment: Okay deleted comment. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for alternative script:

```
#!/bin/sh -ex

destdir="/var/www/html/phpmyadmin"

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' EXIT    # remove temporary directory on termination

wget -O "$tmpdir/archive.zip" \
    "https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip"

cd "$tmpdir" && {
    unzip archive.zip
    rm -f archive.zip

    # The only thing in the current (temporary) directory now is the
    # directory with the unpacked zip file.

    mkdir -p "$destdir"
    mv ./* "$destdir"/
}
```

If the archive unpacks into a subdirectory called `phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages`, the script will move this to `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` so that the contents of the archive is available in `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages`.

The `-ex` makes the script

1. Exit as soon as a utility fails (`-e`), and
2. Output tracing info that could possibly be useful (`-x`).

Running this script twice will cause the last `mv` to fail as there is already a directory with the same name at the destination. The existing directory under `$destdir` will not be modified by this script.

When the script finishes, terminates because of an error, or is killed, the script will remove the temporary directory used for storing and unpacking the downloaded archive.

---

About root and security in this script:

If root permissions are required to write to `$tmpdir` then do *not* run the script as root! Instead insert `sudo` in front of the last `mv`.

There is, what I can see, no risk that any accidental removals will be carried out as the only parameter is `$destdir` and it's never used in any `rm $var1/$var2*` -type commands. In fact, unsetting `$destdir` will make the script fail gracefully at the `mkdir`.